# How to set the vim path to your bash PATH?

Tags: ex-mode, bash, path, environment-variables

I'd like my `$PATH` to be available to vim when running commands with `!`.  How do I set vim's `set path=` to my environment variable `$PATH`?

Comment: Why do you think your `$PATH` is not available when using `:!`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&path` has nothing to do with `$PATH`.

Also `$PATH` is set and used. See `:echo $PATH`.

You should also be able to change its value with `:let $PATH = $PATH.':some/path'` -- there are a few write only things, `$PATH` is not one of them IIRC