# MacVim - doesnt find programs in PATH when running commands using "!"

Tags: gvim, macvim, bash

When I'm using `vim` in a terminal, it uses the `PATH` I have set, and I can run programs and scripts located in my `~/bin` folder using `!`

For example

```
:! some_bash_script.sh
```

When I try this in MacVim, it doesnt find my personal shell scripts. How can I fix this?

I've set my shell in my `~/.vimrc` like so:

```
set shell=/bin/zsh
```

but that doesn't seem to help. I did notice that if I launch MacVim from the command line, it works as expected, i assume because the shell's environment is the environment in which MacVim ends up running in.

e.g.

```
$ open -a MacVim.app
```

Is there a better way to do this? I like launching MacVim using Spotlight, but it doesnt work if I do it that way, only via Terminal.

NOTE: This is [similar to this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13130/9850), but that was for `vim`, not `gvim` or `MacVim`

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/31353/358509 has MacVim solutions for the `PATH`.

Comment: Is this about zsh or bash?

Comment: I agree with muru's question, and will also say that either shell will read different dotfiles (and thus potentially create different `$PATH`s) depending on whether it's launched as a login shell, etc. `:echo $PATH` in MacVim will tell you exactly what `$PATH` it's seeing, but I'm sure that won't give you additional info. You'll probably need to set your path in a shell dotfile that's read regardless of how the shell is launched.

Comment: The [answer i posted here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15740/9850) allows you to use whatever shell you use (as it uses whatever you have set in Terminal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/a/1323375/347397). The problem is that zsh (and other shells) only runs `~/.zshrc` for interactive shells and `~/.zprofile` for "login" shells.

To force running commands as a login shell, add the `-l` flag to either the `shell` option, or the `shellcmdflag` option. That is (in your `~/.gvimrc`),

```
set shell=/bin/zsh\ -l
" or
set shellcmdflag=-l\ -c
```

You need to escape the spaces because of how the `set` command works. Putting it in your `~/.gvimrc` will prevent `$PATH` from growing when running it from the terminal.

Comment: hey! I tried this, but couldnt get it to work. I put it in my `~/.vimrc`, `~/.gvimrc` and the system files used by MacVim, but no difference in executing programs. I tried it with both lines, to no effect (ie - it couldnt find anything I had in my `~/bin` folder, which is in my path)

Comment: Worth noting that `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv ` is sourced for non-interactive shells, but I wouldn't really recommend customizing `$PATH` in there.

Comment: Where do you define your path? `:!` runs commands non-interactively, so you should define `$PATH` in `.zprofile`, not `.zshrc`.

Otherwise, I'm out of ideas. I tested and implemented this fix just before writing the answer.

Comment: @brhfl why not?

Comment: Only defining `$PATH` in `~/.zprofile` worked for me. Adding the `-l` flag to the `shell` or `shellcmdflag` Vim option like suggested in this answer was unnecessary. This is weird because it means that `~/.zprofile` is still read despite Vim running a non-login shell (`set shell` returns `/bin/zsh` and `set shellcmdflag` returns `-c` by default).

Answer (score 2):

So far, my best solution is to launch MacVim using an alternate application launcher, which you can create using AppleScript like so:

1. Create an apple script like by Running "Script Editor", clicking "New Document", and supplying the following:

   ```
   tell application "Terminal"
        do script "open -a MacVim.app; exit"
        delay 5
       quit
   end tell
   ```
2. Export that as an application, by

   - choosing "File | Export"
   - choose "File Format" as "Application"
   - Click "Save", and call it whatever you like. I called mine `MacVimLauncher.app`, and I saved it under `Applications`
3. Run that instead of `MacVim.app`.

Note: If you have MacVim running, you have to shut it down before trying this out. I've had [a similar problem with Eclipse in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38592434/26510), and this should solve that issue as well!